# Inline SVG in vuejs component

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, vue.js

I have created a Vuejs project using @vue/cli version 3.0.0-beta.16 and in my Home.vue single file component I want to import and add inline SVG in the template but I am having trouble doing so.

The problem is vue cli is already using .svg file extension for file-loader like so:

```
webpackConfig.module
  .rule('svg')
    .test(/\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/)
    .use('file-loader')
      .loader('file-loader')
      .options({
        name: getAssetPath(options, `img/[name].[hash:8].[ext]`)
      })
```

I have already tried using the html-loader plugin for including svg in the template and it works fine if I clear the svg default use in my vue.config.js and add my own loader like this:

```
// vue.config.js

chainWebpack: config => {
    const svgRule = config.module.rule('svg')

    // clear all existing loaders.
    // if you don't do this, the loader below will be appended to
    // existing loaders of the rule.
    svgRule.uses.clear()

    // add replacement loader(s)
    svgRule
    .test(/\.(svg)$/)
    .use('html-loader')
    .loader('html-loader')
    .options({
    })
}
```

and in my template:

```
// Home.vue

<div v-html="require('./../assets/inline.svg')"></div>
```

But the problem is it also replaces svg src in the `<img />` tags with inline svg code. What I want is use file-loader for `<img src="something.svg" />` and use html-loader for `require('./inline.svg')`. How do I use multiple loaders for same rule in webpack? Or is it the right approach? Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**
I think the problem is I'm adding the both loaders the wrong way. This is how I add them in my file:

```
// vue.config.js

svgRule
.test(/\.(svg)$/)
.use('file-loader')
.loader('file-loader')
.options({
  name: getAssetPath(options, `img/[name].[ext]`)
})

svgRule
.test(/\.(svg)$/)
.use('html-loader')
.loader('html-loader')
.options({
  attrs: ['div:v-html']
})
```

Comment: Hope, It`s help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49383528/vue-loader-different-loaders-for-one-extension

Answer (score 6):

You can add a leading `!` in the require expression to "override" existing loaders set up by the webpack config.

```
<div v-html="require('!html-loader!./../assets/inline.svg')"></div>
```

This will work without changes to the `vue.config.js` (as long as html-loader is installed)

---

Also, instead of using html-loader look into [svg-inline-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/svg-inline-loader) in can add hashes to classes and ids, so you don't need to worry about name collisions if you have multiple inline svgs on your page.

Comment: This works great except when trying to load a .svg from a variable such as `<div v-html="require(\`!html-loader!${mySvg}\`)"></div>`. Any idea if there's a way to make this work?

Comment: @tettoffensive I don't think that's relevant to loader override unless it somehow prevents webpack from recognizing the expression. Read the following doc page and see if it helps https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/ You should have your path with . as part of the string `./${mySvg}` not just `${mySvg}` i. e. keep the variable to the smallest possible part of the path or better avoid variables in imports in general

Comment: FWIW this doesn't appear to work in Vue 3

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have `html-loader` installed simply execute

```sh
yarn add -D html-loader
```

Then add the following object to the `rules` array in your webpack config file:

```js
{
  test: /\.svg$/,
  use: [{ loader: 'html-loader' }]
}
```

And finally, you will be able to import `svg` files to your scripts with the inline loader.

```js
require('!html-loader!./../assets/inline.svg')

// or directly in your v-html directive
<div v-html="require('!html-loader!./../assets/inline.svg')"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just tell Webpack which loader to use:

```
<div v-html="require('html-loader!./../assets/inline.svg')"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried that but it does not seem to work if I don't add html-loader in my vue.config file and if I add then file-loader stops working. I can't figure out what is the right way to add both loaders.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use both webpack loaders, but also to tell your html loader to restrict to `div` elements with `v-html` with the following syntax in the loader options:

```
{
  attrs: ['div:v-html']
}
```

Docs for the html loader are [found there](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader).

Comment: I tried that but it is working only if I remove the file-loader and in that case `<img src="something.svg" />` does not work. I can't seem to figure out how to use both loaders.
PS: This is how I add both loaders:
 svgRule
    // .test(/\.(svg)(\?.*)?$/)
    .test(/\.(svg)$/)
    .use('file-loader')
    .loader('file-loader')
    .options({
      name: getAssetPath(options, `img/[name].[ext]`)
    })

svgRule
    .test(/\.(svg)$/)
    .use('html-loader')
    .loader('html-loader')
    .options({
    })